# Undefined function or variable 'logsumexp' for input type 'double' when using the pmtk library for HMM?

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-models

I am using the [pmtk library](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3) for continuous observations in HMM for my project. While using the function hmmFit, it is returning the error as stated above. I thought the path of function is missing but the function itself is not in the library. There is already an [issue](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3/issues/29) opened in GitHub, unfortunately with no solution. Could any please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not install the dependencies [mentioned in the readme](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3). The missing function is part of [the lightspeed toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/). You don't have to install the dependencies individually, the support package collects all dependencies.

Comment: How can I provide the known state sequence in hmmFit() function for training the model in pmtk library. Thanks. @daniel